# Get the matched URL in `route` function in Cypress

Tags: url, routes, cypress

In `route` we can specify the `regex` or `minimatch` string to capture any matching URLs', how can I get the matched URL completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from xhr like this:

```
    cy.route('/users/**').as('getPage');
    cy.wait("@getPage").then((xhr) => {
      url = xhr.url;
      console.log('Matched url: ' + url);
    });
```

Hope it helps :)